# Querying Sqlite db with variable

Tags: python, sqlite

Trying to learn Sqlite and I'm not sure I understand why I can't get this code to work:

```
def get_bday(self):
    name = self.input_name()
    self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE name =?', name)
    for row in self.c.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

The `name` variable is being returned from another method.  For this example, I am using "joe smoe" without the quotes as the name variable to perform the query with.  When I run the above code I get:

```
self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE name =?', name)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.
```

The word "joe smoe" is 8 bindings long if you count the space.  But I have no idea what that means. I assumed I could simply pass a variable right to Sqlite just as easily as I pass variables around in Python but that doesn't appear to be the case. I think it has something to do with my very poor understanding of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is currently thinking you want to query each individual letter of `'joe smoe'`.

All you have to do to avoid this is put `name` in a container of some kind: a tuple or a list for example:

```
def get_bday(self):
    name = self.input_name()
    self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE name =?', (name,))
    #                                                       ^    ^^
    for row in self.c.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

Comment: That did it!  I need to read up on passing python variables around to sqlite.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you :-) The [DB-API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) is a good place to start I think.